# Execute 2 ng-repeat loop with odd and even logic

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have 2 tables in which I want to show odd and even records using `ng-repeat`.

I want my odd records to be displayed at the top and even records to be displayed after odd records.

> For Table 1 tag: odd logic
>
> For Table 2 tag: even logic

This is my code:

```
<table>
   <tr>
      <td ng-repeat="item in Users" ng-if="$odd" >
         <!--some other codes-->  
         <!--show div1-->   
         <div ng-if="item.Experience > 0" >
         </div>
         <!--show div2-->   
         <div ng-if="item.Experience == 0" >
         </div>
      </td>
   </tr>
</table>

<table>
   <tr>
      <td ng-repeat="item in Users" ng-if="$even" >
         <!--some other codes-->  
         <!--show div1-->   
         <div ng-if="item.Experience > 0" >
         </div>
         <!--show div2-->   
         <div ng-if="item.Experience == 0" >
         </div>
      </td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

**json output:**

```
[
  {
    "UserId": 1,
    "Experience":2
  },
  { 
    "UserId": 2,
    "Experience":0
  }
]
```

But here odd record i.e `UserId 1` is displayed after the even record that is `User Id 2` is coming on top and with `User 1` coming down.

Answer (score 4):

Try this. for `odd` records

```
 <tr ng-repeat="item in Users" ng-if="item.UserId %2 == 1">
         <td>
          {{item.UserId}}
          </td>
  </tr>
```

and for `even` records:

```
    <tr ng-repeat="item in Users" ng-if="item.UserId %2 == 0">
         <td>
           {{item.UserId}}
          </td>
   </tr>
```

Comment: Now consider I have 4 user Id like this:1,2,3,4 and if i delete user id 1 and 3 then records with id 2 and 4 will be displayed in only even section right as per you logic where as i still want user id 2 to be displayed in odd section and 4 to be displayed in even section

Comment: `$index` in `ng-repeat` begin by 0 . see this https://plnkr.co/edit/w6IJ1vfNcqtNURUSwCsV?p=preview

Comment: Yes you are right :), I was concentrating on ng-if sorry my bad.

Comment: So when i have added $even to first table and $odd to my second table and i have 3 records so first record comes in first table but 2nd and 3rd record comes in the second table

Answer (score 3):

Here is the plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/84dbmzTPgHTi3x8WmKOM?p=preview

```
<html><head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.5/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="app.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-app="app" ng-controller=" ActCtrl">

<table>
       <tr ng-repeat="item in data1" ng-if="$odd">
              <td>{{ $index + 1 }}


                <!--some other codes-->  
               <!--show div1-->   
                <div class="odd"  ng-if="item.Experience > 0" >
                </div>

               <!--show div2-->   
                <div class="odd" ng-if="item.Experience == 0" >
                </div>
              </td>
       </tr>
 </table>


 <table>
       <tr ng-repeat="item in data1" ng-if="$even">
              <td>{{ $index + 1 }}

                <!--some other codes-->  
               <!--show div1-->   
                <div class="even" ng-if="item.Experience > 0" >
                </div>

               <!--show div2-->   
                <div class="even" ng-if="item.Experience == 0" >
                </div>
              </td>
       </tr>
 </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: My row i.e tr tag will be 1 in which my td tag generation would be depending upon the number of times this loop will run